# 2 GPU different technologies Maxwell and Pascal Rendering Together

Tags: gpu

is it possible to use 2 gpus with different technologies for final render. specifically **Maxwel Titan X** and ***Pascal Titan XP***.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Nvidia CUDA is supported for GPU rendering on Nvidia graphics cards. Supported graphics cards start from GTX 4xx (computing capability 2.0). Both of your listed cards have compute capability 2.0. For them to work all you should need is the latest Nvidia drivers.

Source: [The Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, do you intall in your primary slot the newest video card whit it latest driver and move the old card to another slot..? I recently migrate from many many max years to Blender....and being Cycles a solid engine, I want go further with this,
I really apreciate your comments.

Comment: @Felipe As far as I know slot order does not matter for whether it works or not. I've been able to run my 2x 760s and a 1080 in a few configurations. Not sure if it effects performance though.